# Applying change to default value of a column

Tags: mysql

I recently applied changes to a column by adding default values to a column of datatype **datetime**. But it doesn't apply to the already existing columns. Am i missing anything?

Comment: alter table rooms modify column timedate datetime default now();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work such way because at the time you're changing column's default value, your records **already exist**. To change them, use `UPDATE`, like:

```
UPDATE t SET col='new_default_value'
```

default value is the thing which is applied to **newly created** rows if the corresponding column value was not set.

Comment: update rooms set timedate=now() where timedate=null;  Why didn't this work pal?

Comment: because `=null` has no sense (you can't compare "some value" and "absence of value" on equality). Use `WHERE timedate IS NULL` instead